# How do I retrieve POST data after Auth?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

Wether I submit the login, register, or forgot password form I can't retrieve the POST data. While this is my form tag:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/login') }}">
```

It doesn't end up in `/login` so I'm guessing it gets redirected back to the current page. How do I retrieve this data anyway?

My goal is to know if a person has used the register/login/or forgot password form wether it failed or was successfull. (They are all on the same page in different modals)

EDIT:

My controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Blog;
use App\Account;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //$this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $blogItems = Blog::all();
        $onlinePlayers = Account::getOnlinePlayers()->count();
        $onlineStaff = Account::getOnlineStaff()->count();
        $input = Request('username');
        return Auth::routes();
    }
}
```

The login form:

```
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/login') }}">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('username') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="username" class="col-md-4 control-label">Username</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" value="{{ old('username') }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('username'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('username') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                        <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>

                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" required>

                            @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                <span class="help-block">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                <label>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="remember" {{ old('remember') ? 'checked' : '' }}> Remember Me
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                Login
                            </button>

                            <a class="btn btn-link" href="{{ url('/password/reset') }}">
                                Forgot Your Password?
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

My Routes:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

//Auth
Auth::routes();

//Homepage
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index');
Route::get('/logout', '\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout');
```

LoginController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use \Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Account;

class LoginController extends Controller 
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    /**
    * Override the username method used to validate login
    *
    * @return string
    */
    public function username()
    {
        return 'username';
    }
}
```

Comment: What is in your routes file for the `/login` route?

Comment: I have `Auth::routes();` in my controller it must be defined in there.

Comment: I think we need to see a little bit more code to grasp what your problem is

Comment: I've editted my question with my code

Answer (score 1):

Definitely you can. You can retrieve the login data via the following command:

If your html is:

```
<input type="text" name="username"/><br/>
<input type="password" name="password"/><br/>
```

Then inside the controller action, use the following command:

```
string username = Request["username"];
string password = Request["password"];
```

Comment: That's not working. It says the constant does not exist. When I use `$request` instead the value is empty. And so is request('username')